# Change system font on 4.2.2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.2-jelly-bean, settings, fonts

On my GT-I9105P with 4.1.2 there was a section in the Settings where I could change the system font. But now I've done the 4.2.2 upgrade and the Settings have been redesigned I can't find any option to change the system font. How can I change it?

P.S. I would not use any applications to change the font, so I wanna know if the option to change the font have been removed or simply I can't find it.

EDIT: I found the solution.

Comment: Are you running an official Samsung firmware? It should be in Settings > Display > Font Style. Failing that there are apps, maybe they would be worth considering? I have the option on a Touchwiz ROM on the S4 but not on the 4.4 Google Edition.

Comment: @RossC, Based on my experience, this seems like an entirely valid answer. I'd be happy to upvote it if posted as an answer.

Comment: What was the solution? Could you share it here, and accept it as an answer 2 days later?